# How to perform signed comparison between unsigned operands?

Tags: c, casting, integer, unsigned, signed

I have declared 4 unsigned variables:

```
uint32_t empty_bucket;
uint32_t base_bucket;
uint32_t hop_size;
uint32_t ht_size;
```

I want to perform a signed conditional check:

```
if (empty_bucket < base_bucket + (hop_size - 1) - ht_size)
```

Knowing that `base_bucket + (hop_size - 1) - ht_size` could be a negative value. What is the right casting for the operands to perform this singed operation?

*NB:* `base_bucket + (hop_size - 1) - ht_size` could be something really close to `-2^32`, so casting to signed 32-bits `int32_t` could cause an overflow.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. An unsigned integer cannot become negative by definition. Nor can the difference become negative. Overflow/underflow **of unsigned integers** wraps, but the result is still positive (read about modulo-arithmetic). If you cast the operands of the expression to a signed, you invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf it does make sense. `base_bucket + (hop_size - 1) - ht_size` could be negative. Read this as: mathematically this expression can be negative, but in C because I use unsigned types I get the unsigned modulo behavior. How can I make my C code to behave like the mathematical model?

Comment: @bolov: Yes, but only if `int` is larger than `uint32_t`. Otherwise it cannot. You want to recap the chapter about arithmetic operators. But why do you have a sock-puppet account?

Comment: @Olaf sock puppet account? What do you mean?

Comment: @Olaf , i exactly wanted what #bolov expressed in a better way than i did. i mean, mathematically, i want to check against that negative value. i casted everything to signed 64-bits before posting but it wasn't based on a clear understanding.

Comment: " How can I make **my** C code to behave like the mathematical model?" - Sounds like you mean the one in the question which is from a different user-name. Honesly sorry if I that was just some missphrasing.

Comment: @Olaf no worries. No, I have no affiliation with afr0ck or this question. I was just trying to rephrase (from his perspective). No apologies needed, I see now how it sounded.

Comment: @bolov: Yes, sorry anyway, There's just too many trolls and socks around here lately :-\

Comment: Is there some reason you can't change the conditional to: `if (empty_bucket + ht_size < base_bucket + (hop_size - 1))`?

Comment: Please be more specific about the variables and their **guaranteed** ranges (assert they cannot be outside in your code!).

Comment: @DavidBowling I know, that's what I'm actually using in my code. I only wanted to understand the cast in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `stdint` include, you could convert the operands to 64 bit signed values, and compare that, no risk that any of the terms to the right become negative, and we have to cast the left operand to signed integer to avoid undefined/implementation behaviour when comparing signed/unsigned:

```
if ((int64_t)empty_bucket < ((int64_t)base_bucket + ((int64_t)hop_size - 1) - (int64_t)ht_size))
```

To sum it up:

- no risk of overflow (I may have cast a little too much on the right side)
- comparison between signed entities
- On the downside, 64 bit conversion may have a negative impact on the performance on a 32 bit architecture

Comment: This is exactly what i thought about & tried before posting, i got what i wanted (The negative values) but i thought there might be a better way to do it based on a better comprehension.

Comment: when people hear "a negative impact on the performance" they have mostly knee jerk reaction and put too much weight on it. Unless we are talking about some limited embedded system, using 64 bits operands instead of 32 will have almost no impact especially when we don't have multiplication or division.

Comment: Using 64 bit integers is not favourable on most smaller systems. It should be avoided when possible (and it sems to be).

Comment: @bolov I added "on a 32 bit architecture".

Comment: @bolov exactly, I'm working on 64-bits desktop machine & those little performance hurts ain't a big deal for me. Actually, I'm implementing a wrap around version of Hopscotch hashmap & want to measure performance between shadowed version and a bitmap version.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (base_bucket + hop_size > ht_size + 1
    && empty_bucket < base_bucket + (hop_size - 1) - ht_size)
```

The first line checks if the right side of the comparison we want to perform is indeed a positive integer. It is done by checking that all the positive values (`base_bucket` and `hop_size`) are greater than all the negative values (`- 1` and `- ht_size`). It does this without using subtractions, so it is safe to do with unsigned integers.

@David Bowling suggested

```
if (empty_bucket + ht_size < base_bucket + (hop_size - 1))
```

the idea is basically the same, to make sure that both sides of the comparison are always positive. This works if `base_bucket` and `hop_size` are not both zero at the same time.

With both solutions there can theoretically still be overflow, you have to check that with your actual values. If there is overflow, use a larger type.

<sup>Please disregard my earlier mention of short-circuit evaluation, because it is not relevant. If the integer sizes are 'normal', eg. 16, 32, or 64 bits, this should work.</sup>

Comment: Please elaborate why there will be warnings.

Comment: Comparing unsigned with signed?

Comment: If `int` is larger than `uint32_t`, all is coerced to `int` anyway. Otherwise it is all `unsigned` or whatever `uint322_t` is. I didn't check it in detail, but yes, that could be the way. I'd check for border-cases, though (at last one good use for unit-tests - yessss).

Comment: Yes, no promotion allowed if int is 32 bit because the signed int can't hold all the values. The warning I mentioned is really not relevant here, my mistake.

Comment: I still have a problem with the addition. Without more information/guarantees from OP, there still can be wrap here (and hop_size - 1) can wrap, too.

Comment: @alain i don't actually understand you answer, can you explain in more details ?

Comment: @afr0ck: Read my comments. Anyway, if you can/want to afford, the 64 bit version might be faster. If in doubt, profile/benchmark - **properly**.

Comment: @Olaf I understood afr0ck's assertion of "base_bucket + (hop_size - 1) - ht_size could be something really close to -2^32" as implying that these values can be computed.

Comment: @alain still trying to understand what you wrote over there !